# iOS animation warning on sliding menu (SASlideMenuVC)

Tags: ios, animation, uigesturerecognizer, slide, saslidemenu

I am getting "Multiple gravity behaviour per animator is undefined and may assert in the future" in debugger. I think it is because i use custom [SASlideMenu view controller] (https://github.com/stefanoa/SASlideMenu).
What is it?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the code where `UIGravityBehavior` objects are created and added to the `UIDynamicAnimator` instance. It seems behaviors are accumulating in the animator (and not being released when completing the action).

This project has the same issue https://github.com/simonwhitaker/ioscon-2014-demo. It can be solved using `- (void)removeBehavior:(UIDynamicBehavior *)behavior`:

```
- (IBAction)dismissAlertView:(id)sender {
    UIGravityBehavior *gravity = [[UIGravityBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[self.alertView]];

    gravity.magnitude = 4;
    __weak __typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    __weak __typeof__(gravity) weakGravity = gravity;

    gravity.action = ^{
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        if (!CGRectIntersectsRect(strongSelf.alertView.frame, strongSelf.alertBackgroundView.bounds)) {

            //[strongSelf.animator removeAllBehaviors];
            [strongSelf.animator removeBehavior:weakGravity];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
                strongSelf.alertBackgroundView.alpha = 0.0;
            }];
        }
    };

    [self.animator addBehavior:gravity];
}
```